# PyODBC result to a dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

I'm trying to make a dictionary with a result using `fetchall()`.

I will try to explain what I need; I have the following code in Python:

```
conexiones = crsr_kala.execute("SELECT dst_srv, dst_db FROM info_skill_vdn_campana WHERE activo = 1 AND pbx = 'V2' GROUP BY dst_srv;").fetchall()
```

And this is the out in SQL:

[image: OUT]

So with this on Python I want to make a dictionary, now I have the next code:

```
col = [column[0] for column in conexiones]
res = []
for row in conexiones:
    res.append(dict(zip(col, row)))
cox2 = collections.defaultdict(set)
for d in res:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        cox2[k].add(v)
```

But this is the output:

[image: OUT]

And I want to have the following out:

```
{'172.59.xx.xx': set([PBX_es]), '172.65.xx.xx': set([PBX_pt]), '172.72.xx.xx': set([PBX_mx])}
```

But, I have no idea how to edit my actual code to have that output.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overthinking it. You first built a list of `{'dst_srv': .., 'dst_db': ..}`, but you don't really need it.

```
cox2 = collections.defaultdict(set)
for k,v in conexiones:
    cox2[k].add(v)
```

Comment: It works! But do you know if there is a way to change the value set to str?

Comment: what do you mean by set to str? like `{'1','2'}` to `1,2`?